# How can i disable youtube logo in ytplayer in ios swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have Implemented ytplayer in my project , but how can i disable YOUTUBE LOGO in Ytplayerview.

Acually i have added "modestbranding" : 1 parameter but it's not working. still i'm getting youtube logo in videoplayer.

please suggest me with proper answer.. Thanks in advc

`playerVars = [ "controls" : 1 , "playsinline" : 1, "autoplay" : 1, // "autohide" : 1, "rel" : 0, "showinfo" : 0, // "showing" : 1, "color" : "white", "cc_load_policy" : 1, "iv_load_policy" : 1, "modestbranding" : 1 ]self.player.load(withVideoId: "yvhrORy4x30",playerVars: playerVars)`

Comment: Try to find it in asset and remove it from there, But I suggest you try to make the app without disabling it.

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: playerVars = [
            "controls" : 1 ,
            "playsinline" : 1,
            "autoplay" : 1,
         //   "autohide" : 1,
            "rel" : 0,
           "showinfo" : 0,
        //    "showing" : 1,
            "color" : "white",
            "cc_load_policy" : 1,
            "iv_load_policy" : 1,
        
        "modestbranding" : 1
            
        ]self.player.load(withVideoId: "yvhrORy4x30",playerVars: playerVars)

Comment: use this library  'youtube-ios-player-helper'

Comment: @Naveen Have you find answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet:

```
let playerVars = [
            "modestbranding": 1,
            "controls" : 1,
            "rel" : 0,
            "fs" : 1,
            "playsinline" : 1,
            "origin" : "https://www.example.com",
            "showinfo" : 0
        ] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: These are the parameters you need to supply to remove logo and info

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT completely remove the youtube branding.

You can play around with setting:
modestbranding=1 - to remove the youtube logo and
showinfo=0 to remove the title and uploader info

Comment: Thank you ,,but is there any other players for playing youtube videos

Answer (score 0):

Setting Color: “white”, will disable modestbranding.
Leave it to be the default red colour